# problem with sending post request in react

Tags: reactjs

this is the structure of our service:

[image]

and this is my post method in react:

```
const handleSubmitFrom =(info) => {
        generalPostWithBody({first_name: info['firstName'] ,birth_date:info['miladi'] ,email:info['email'],
            address:[
                {
                    postal_code: info['postalCode'],
                    address: info['address']
                }]
            ,
            physical_activity: "Very Lightly Active",
            age: info['age'],
            last_name:info['lastName'],
            gender:"M",
            sport_fields: [100]
        }, `/user/profile`).then(resp => {
            if (resp.status === 201) {
                console.log('ok')
            }
        }, error => {
            console.log('not ok')
        });
    }
```

the problem is that this do not post the address. I mean this is my post response :

[image]

and at last this is my state:

```
const [infos, setInfos] = useState({
        firstName: '',
        lastName:'',
        DOB: '',
        mobile: '',
        email: '',
        postalCode: '33',
        address: 'sghgfchgk',
        miladi: '2002-01-19',
        age:0,

    });
```

Comment: here info is correct I edit the question .and both address and postalCode are string.

Comment: let me show `generalPostWithBody()`

Comment: Maybe It because your backend doesn't return address property or It's having error and cannot add address property. Can you post your back-end code and add more tags to this question

Comment: sadly I don't have the back-end codes and other members of my team work on that . but when I call get method it gets address from service but its empty because I can not post any data in address!